# How would I go about storing individual variables from a passed in @Binding variable?

Tags: swiftui

My @Binding weight variable connects to my Source of Truth further up in my code. But I also need to let my user edit this with a TextField(). So, I am trying to create a local variable of type String because TextField requires type Bindable.

Perhaps I'm approaching this wrong.

```
struct SetsBar: View {
    @Binding var weight: Int
    @Binding var reps: Int
    
    @State var weightString: String = String(weight)

    
    init(weight: Binding<Int>, reps: Binding<Int>) {
        self._weight = weight
        self._reps = reps
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            TextField("\(weight)", text: $weightString)
        }
    }
}
```

I get an error on my @State property

```
Cannot use instance member 'weight' within property initializer; property initializers run before 'self' is available
```

Answer (score 1):

You can bind `weight` directly using `TextField` variant with formatter (configuring formatter as much as needed, below is simplified variant for demo), like

```
var body: some View {
    HStack {
        TextField("\(weight)", value: $weight, formatter: NumberFormatter())
    }
}
```

Comment: `Formatter`s are the old way; `FormatStyle` is the current. Use the `format` argument instead.

Comment: not a good idea to init objects in body